# Decrease of Bicarbonate to compensate Respiratory alkalosis

Tags: biochemistry

I am studying this claim

> Compensatory mechanism in respiratory alkalosis is decrease of SB i.e. bicarbonate ions ($\ce{HCO3^-}$).

There are reactions

$\ce{HCO3- \rightarrow H+ + CO3^{2-}}$ (conjugate base)

and

$\ce{HCO3- + H+ \rightarrow H2CO3}$ (conjugate acid)

but since the $pK_a$ for the second reaction is greater

- decrease in $\ce{HCO3-}$ yields more acids

so alleviates respiratory alkalosis.

To claim such a thing, I think you must know that the $pK_a$ for the reaction is greater, so change in bicarbonate ions' content results in bigger change in the second reaction.

**How does the decrease of bicarbonate ions lead to decreased respiratory alkalosis?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bicarbonate ion is amphiprotic, as you've recognized. It can react as both a Brønsted base and as a Brønsted acid in water solution:

As an acid:

$K_a = 4.8 * 10^{-11}$

$\ce{HOCO_2^- + H_2O <=> OH_3^+ + CO_3^{2-}}$

As a base:

$K_b = 2.1 * 10^{-4}$

$\ce{HOCO_2^- + H_2O <=> HO^- + H_2CO_3}$ (not really true carbonic acid).

Through K value inspection, we can see that the bicarbonate ion preferentially reacts as a base in water solution. The magnitude of this difference is massive; $K_b$ is more than a million times greater than $K_a$.

So by decreasing the concentration of bicarbonate ion, we can combat respiratory alkalosis.

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer! I had bad time in recalling this today.

Comment: It is my pleasure!

Comment: Hmm. I think this situation changes in different pH. How does bicarbonate work in pH 7.4, 7.0 and 7.8? Still as a base? I think as a base at 7.8. But as a acid at 7.8 probably. Probably as a base at 7.4.

Comment: Why do you say that? How can you support your claims?

Comment: They are hypothesis. I just recall that bicarbonate work differently in different pH.